# How to solve yarn container sizing issue on spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I want to launch some pyspark jobs on `YARN`.  I have 2 nodes, with 10 GB each.  I am able to open up the pyspark shell like so:  `pyspark`

Now when I have a very simple example that I try to launch:

```
import random
NUM_SAMPLES=1000
def inside(p):
    x, y = random.random(), random.random()
    return x*x + y*y < 1

count = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, NUM_SAMPLES)) \
             .filter(inside).count()
print "Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
```

I get as a result a very long spark log with the error output.  The most important information is:

```
ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on (ip>: Container marked as failed: <containerID> on host: <ip>. Exit status 1.  Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.  ......
```

later on in the logs I see...

```
ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times: aborting job
INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 1
INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 1 has been removed (new total is 0)
```

From what I'm gathering from the logs above, this seems to be a container sizing issue in yarn.

My `yarn-site.xml` file has the following settings:

```
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 10240
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 10240
```

and in `spark-defaults.conf` contains:

```
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048
spark.driver.memory=3g
```

If there are any other settings you'd like to know about, please let me know.

How do I set the container size in yarn appropriately?
(bounty on the way for someone who can help me with this)

Comment: Try starting your Pyspark session with higher executor memory "

    pyspark --master yarn --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 4g"

Comment: I'll try that.  What does that have to do with yarn container size?

Comment: executor runs in a YARN container. By defining executor memory your container size.

Comment: there is no overhead memory size?

Comment: @Rags I think that is incorrect.  The executor size is not necessarily the size of the YARN container.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let me first explain the basic set of properties required to tune your spark application on a YARN cluster.

**Note:** Container in YARN is equivalent to Executor in Spark. For understandability, you can consider that both are same.

**On yarn-site.xml:**

`yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` is the total memory available to the cluster from a given node.

`yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` is the total number of CPU vcores available to the cluster from a given node.

`yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` is the maximum memory in mb that can be allocated per yarn container.

`yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores` is the maximum number of vcores that can be allocated per yarn container.

**Example:** If a node has 16GB and 8vcores and you would like to contribute 14GB and 6vcores to the cluster(for containers), then set properties as shown below:

> yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb : 14336 (14GB)
>
> yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores : 6

And, to create containers with 2GB and 1vcore each, set these properties:

> yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb : 2049
>
> yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores : 1

**Note:** Even though there is enough memory(14gb) to create 7 containers with 2GB, above config will only create 6 containers with 2GB and only 12GB out of 14GB will be utilized to the cluster. This is because there are only 6vcores available to the cluster.

**Now on Spark side,**

Below properties specify memory to be requested per executor/container

`spark.driver.memory`

`spark.executor.memory`

Below properties specify vcores to be requested per executor/container

`spark.driver.cores`

`spark.executor.cores`

**IMP:** **All the Spark's memory and vcore properties should be less than or equal to what YARN's configuration**

Below property specifies the total number of executors/containers that can be used for your spark application from the YARN cluster.

`spark.executor.instances`

This property should be less than the total number of containers available in the YARN cluster.

Once the yarn configuration is complete, the spark should request for containers **that can be allocated based on the YARN configurations**. That means if YARN is configured to allocate a maximum of 2GB per container and Spark requests a container with 3GB memory, then the job will either halt or stop because YARN cannot satisfy the spark's request.

**Now for your use case:**
Usually, cluster tuning is based on the workloads. But below config should be more suitable.

*Memory available*: 10GB * 2 nodes
*Vcores available*: 5 * 2 vcores [Assumption]

**On yarn-site.xml** [In both the nodes]

> `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` : 10240
>
> `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` : 5
>
> `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` : 2049
>
> `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores` : 1

Using above config, you can create a maximum of 10 containers on each of the nodes having 2GB,1vcore per container.

**Spark config**

> `spark.driver.memory`  1536mb
>
> `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` 512mb
>
> `spark.executor.memory`  1536mb
>
> `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` 512mb
>
> `spark.driver.cores`  1
>
> `spark.executor.cores`  1
>
> `spark.executor.instances` 19

Please feel free to play around these configurations to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you @code.  Now, I'm curious to know more about the properties `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb`.  Why not just always make `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` as large as your `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`, and make `yarn-scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` as small as possible?  That way, you always have enough room to support an executor via the maximum, and you always have enough granularity to support no more memory than is required because of the minimum?

Comment: Finally:  Don't we need to save room for the OS, etc., so we should set `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` to something less than 10G, say 8192 GB?

Comment: You can make `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` as large as your `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`, and make `yarn-scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` as small as possible. Because Spark is the one who is going to request the resources and it should be configured so that it makes the best use of resources and achieves the better parallelism.
Coming to the second question, you are right, you have to leave some space and vcore for OS and other system services(I though your nodes had 10GB excluding OS requirements). In my experience, 1vcore and 2gb should be enough for a Linux based server.

Comment: So there is never a good reason to make `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` less than `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`, correct?  (And thanks so much for your answer btw)

Comment: If you are running only Spark on YARN cluster, then I don't see any good reason. Not sure about Spark's dynamic resource allocation though. In the case of dynamic resource allocation, to limit the resource requests, these properties might become useful.

Comment: `spark.executor.instances 19` - could you explain on how it will behave?

Comment: Sorry, it has been a long time since I moved away from Spark. But I'll try my best. The above configuration was given for a cluster of two nodes, with an estimated number of containers per node=10. So out of total 20 containers, we are configuring Spark to request for 19 executors(or containers). Leaving 1 container out, for the Spark Driver itself, assuming the Spark app is running in cluster mode.